# Why does my custom ASP.Net control become its base control upon postback?

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls, postback

In order to customize the aspect of some nodes in a `TreeView` control, I've created a custom control derived from the `TreeNode` class, which overrides the `RenderPreText` and `RenderPostText` methods.

This works fine... until the user clicks on anything in the page. As soon as a postback is made, all TreeNodes lose their custom aspect.

I've inspected the code with the debugger, and I've discovered that all the `TreeNode`s are being created as `MyCustomTreeNode` objects, but after the postback they just become standard `TreeNode`s.

What's happening here?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer found, as documented here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2527108.

Creating a custom control derived from `TreeNode` is not enough, two other steps are required:

- Enable the control to save its additional properties in the viewstate.
- Create another custom control derived from `TreeView`, which knows how to recreate those custom `TreeNode`s when a postback happens.

Comment: Thank you! I'm also implementing a custom node type and that Microsoft article you found was invaluable.